# Получение вывода из subprocess.call

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

ситуация такая что мне нужен именно аргумент .call а не .run, .Popen и.т.д.
Я в курсе что .call возвращает 1 или 0, но мне нужен сам вывод из выполнения команды, к примеру:

subprocess.call('dir', shell=True)

Тут мне необходимо получить список файлов dir, как мне это сделать?
Буду благодарен.

Comment: [«Я в курсе, что микроскоп не предназначен для забивания гвоздей, но мне нужно забить гвоздь именно микроскопом».](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/710) Чем вам run не угодил?

Comment: дело в том что когда я в коде выполняю команды через call можно открыть несколько одноименных процессов а run увы такого не позволяет

Comment: Непонятно о чём речь, что значит «открыть несколько одноименных процессов» и почему run не позволяет?

Comment: когда я пишу subprocess.call('start calc', shell=True) python запускает этот процесс как вызов

Comment: и я могу занести это в цикл

Comment: И в чём проблема написать `subprocess.run('start calc', shell=True)`? Я проверил — работает точно так же

Comment: окей щас чекну)

Comment: Да,спасибо работает и как я могу получить аутпут?

Comment: Ну если вы использовали `start`, то никак, потому что вы таким образом сознательно отказались от любого взаимодействия с созданным процессом. А без start какое-нибудь `subprocess.run('dir', shell=True, capture_output=True).stdout` отлично работает

Comment: спасибо вам огромное

Comment: Привет опять, у меня версия 3.6 для нее чек аутпут не работал,вместо этого я использовал stdout=subprocess.PIPE

Comment: Кроме того мне нужно было запустить несколько процессов,как вы сказали ранее я сознательно отказываюсь от процесса если пишу start.

Comment: Я нашел обходной путь,составив простое условие:start = 'start'
command = 'start calc' с помощью if start in command проверяется условие на содержание слова start если оно есть запускается subprocess.call а если нет то subprocess.run

Comment: Еще раз спасибо вам